# Need to remove GO from string but only if followed or preceded by hidden character or space

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, ssis

I have a string (=SQL query) and I need to remove all `GO` commands.
That could be done simply like this: `REPLACE(<columnname>,'GO','')` but strings like `'Be gone!'`  will suddenly look like `'Be ne!'`

So my idea is to use something like this:

`REPLACE(<columnname>,'GO' + <hidden character>,'')`
 But how to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't `REPLACE(<columnname>,'GO ','')` work? (Extra space behind GO)

Comment: I was thinking about that. Tested that but Go will often be followed by a return and a space does not trap that return. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If returns are also a problem, you'll have to nest `replace` like:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(<columnname>,'GO ',''), CHAR(10)+CHAR(13), '').
```

Note this replaces a `char(10)+char(13)`, which is a windows return (Carriage Return Line Feed). If you (also) have Carriage Returns or Line Feeds without the other, you'll have to correct for that. If you have a combination of possible line endings, you'll have to nest `replace` even further. This should be the general pattern, though.

Answer (score 0):

`replace ([columnA], 'GO' + char(13),'')` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Does this replace a space as well?